# Proving the continuity of $f(x)=e^x$ using delta-epsilon

Tags: proof-writing, epsilon-delta

What I'm stuck on is the way to get from $e^x-e^{x_0}$ to $x-x_0$. I know I could do a log base e to the $e^x-e^{x_0}$ but the algebra wouldn't result in $x-x_0$. I'm mostly just stuck on the logarithm and how to make $e^x-e^{x_0}$ turn into $x-x_0$.

Comment: Sometimes it is easier to use $x_0+h$ and $x_0$ rather than $x_0$ and a general $x$. For instance: $|e^{x_0+h}-e^{x_0}|=|e^{x_0}||e^h-1|$.

Comment: [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1888491/to-prove-ex-is-continuous-function-using-epsilon-and-delta-method?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1222342/is-this-epsilon-delta-approach-to-prove-that-ex-is-continuous-correct) might help!

Comment: @Prototank how can you use $x_0+h$ for x?

Comment: @ChinnapparajR thanks for the links!